# Textarea mouse position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building my chat and everything works fine, I just got a little issue with my texarea, when I'm typing a message I can position my mouse wherever I want I don't want this, I want to "lock" the textarea just to type at the begging of the box, I will leave some images below so you can check it out. I hope you guys can help.

Images:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: I think you should provide some example code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any whitespace between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` is preserved.

So just declare it like that `<textarea></textarea>` and not like that :

```
<textarea>

</textarea>
```

You can test it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b33ncjbb/)

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't know this, it has been fixed now. :)